# Getting error while trying to post: org.hibernate.PropertyValueException: not-null property references a null or transient value

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate

I am trying to save data to my database, but I am getting the following error:
`org.hibernate.PropertyValueException: not-null property references a null or transient value: hu.sze.szakdolgozat.market.entity.OrderDetail.order`

- This is the JSON body: [Click here to
  view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bGlSY.png)
- These are my entitys: [Click here to
  view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nYqDw.png)
- And this is my service: [Click here to
  view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qYNyT.png)

When I try to post without the "orderDetails" in the JSON, it works fine.
I wasted a lot of time trying to figure this one out.
Thank you for your help in advance!

Comment: Please don't add screenshots. I can't see where you set the order on the OrderDetail entity. That's the problem

Comment: How could I set it? I am realy new at this and I am trying to learn.

Comment: You have to call setOrder and pass the created order

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

1. Save OrderDetails in DB
2. Then save OrderDetails in Order.
3. Save this Order to DB.

If this doesn't work share screenshot of your end point.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! It turned out, that I had a few mistakes in my database schema.